# Rows in the Terminal

Tags: ruby, terminal

I am trying to build a game in the terminal that has rooms you can enter. I was hoping to have the rooms displayed side-by-side in 2's, however, I can't get them to line up horizontally.

I am hoping for the terminal to look like this:

--------------------|--------------|
| Green Room       | Blue Room
  |**___________**|**__________**|

But I keep getting this:

|------------------|
| Green Room       |

|**___________**|

|------------------|

|      Blue Room    |
|**___________**|

Here is my code:

```
def green_room
  puts "|------------------|"
  puts "|  Green Room      |"
  puts "|__________________|"
end

def blue_room
  puts "|------------------|"
  puts "|  Blue Room       |"
  puts "|__________________|"
end
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: What language is this in?

Comment: It's in Ruby. Sorry, I had to edit the question. It was displaying incorrectly. The game would be for terminal display only.

Comment: You need `puts "| Green Room  |  Blue Room  |"`, etc. (with no tabs).  Consider using a ["here" documnent](http://log.gmarik.info/2007/12/rubys-here-document-heredoc-mini.html) to hold the string--named `game`, say--and then just `puts game`.

Answer (score 3):

Terminal is a kind of typewriter (they literally were back then). Every time you print a new-line character, the 'caret' moves to the next line.

Not all is lost, however. Most terminals allow cursor positioning. For instance, a lot of terminal emulators support some subset of vt100 [escape sequences](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm) that you could use to position your cursor exactly where you want it to be. That said, you should probably consider using some existing terminal libraries that already take care of this in a more convenient way. Ruby does support [curses](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses.html) library which should let you position stuff on the screen and more.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I'll start checking them out now.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this that I like, it makes everything look nice, generators:

```
def green_room
  ["|------------------|",
   "|  Green Room      |",
   "|__________________|"].to_enum
end

def blue_room
  ["|------------------|",
   "|  Blue Room       |",
   "|__________________|"].to_enum
end

def print_func(*args)
  loop do
    args.each { |x| print x.next }
    puts ""
  end
end

print_func(green_room, blue_room)

# returns the following
|------------------||------------------|
|  Green Room      ||  Blue Room       |
|__________________||__________________|
```

picked due to elegance and composability of the approach. `print` is like puts but doesn't include a newline character.

Gives you a function to put as many rooms as you want next to another on a line, call the function again to do a new line.

Comment: +1. Clever. Next logical step -- figure out how to print blue room at an arbitrary X/Y offset relative to the green one, possibly with an overlap. :-)

Comment: True, you could have a very cool generator method that takes all the other functions (which will have offsets added with x + row_length*y added until it starts and then x added each row) and then will use some or logic for the overlap. So the generator would now add them character by character.